# i'm using AsyncTask in my custom Dialog but the dialog dosnot show

Tags: android

am calling this task by create new object dot execute() but the dialog     dosnot  show  AsyncTask works fine in activity, but inside dialog doesn't show ProgressDialog. Tried do privid context from dialog, from activity who showed dialog, app context. Result is same: no ProgressDialog shown on my screen.
        Any Suggestions?

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RSSFeed> {

    private Exception exception;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public RetrieveFeedTask()
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(RSSReader.this);

    }

    protected RSSFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
             URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

             // create the factory
             SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
             // create a parser
             SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

             // create the reader (scanner)
             XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
             // instantiate our handler
             RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
             // assign our handler
             xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
             // get our data via the url class
             InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
             // perform the synchronous parse           
             xmlreader.parse(is);
             feed=theRssHandler.getFeed();
             // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
             return feed;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }


            TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
            TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
            ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);

            if ( feed == null)
            {
                feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
                return;
            }

            feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
            feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());
            ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());


            itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

            itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(RSSReader.this);

            itemlist.setSelection(0);

        }


    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.dialog.setMessage("لحظة من فضلك");
         this.dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: `dialog = new ProgressDialog(RSSReader.this);` call oncreate section first

Comment: or `public RetrieveFeedTask(RSSReader activity) {
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }
 `

Comment: many thanx still the same isue

Comment: At first call `onPreExecute` then `onPostExecute`

Comment: are you sure it's not appearing? maybe it's too fast!, try to run app after commenting the line `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: @Alaamousa add `Log.d("Dialog_fire","Show");` in pre section and ``Log.d("Dialog_fire","Dismiss");`` postexecute section .Make sure

Comment: @Alaamousa let me feedback please .

Comment: ok , Added to the pre section and postexecute section ,nothing appears on the screen

Comment: @Yazan iam try after comment line dialog.dismiss(); ,still the same isue

Comment: The problem in the order of function first must call  onPreExecute() then doInBackground at the end call onPostExecute

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it work corrctly  thanx for u

Comment: if you have added logs in the methods of the task and nothing appeared in logcat, then it looks that task dose not executed, post the code that starts the task

Comment: @Alaamousa Thanks .See my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

At first you should call `onPreExecute ()`

> invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is
>   normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress
>   bar in the user interface.

Finally `onPostExecute()`

> invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.
>   The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a
>   parameter.

Read official Guideline about **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**